# How to filter out rows of a table from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
TABLE1:
query | info
aa      info
bb      info
aa      info
cc      info
cc      info

TABLE2:
query | info
aa      inf
cc      inf
```

Table 1 can have repeating queries, but 2 cannot

I need an SQL query to get all queries in table 1 that also exist in table 2. If there are multiple corresponding queries in table 1, then there should be multiple in the result
What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.* from table1
join table2 on table1.query=table2.query
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better understanding of solution for the problem.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON 
table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Use Joins

```
SELECT 
 t1.* 
FROM 
table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2  t2 ON t1.query=t2.query
```